# text generation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, output, generator

I am a beginner in Python and I am using Python 2.7. I started work on a project that generate text by using Markov chain. I applied [this](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/tag/text-generator/) with some modifications.

```
#!/usr/bin/env 
# encoding: utf-8


from pprint import pprint
from random import choice

#----------------------build dictionary--------------------------
EOS = ['.', '?', '!']
fname=open(r'C:\Python27\nujudfile.txt', 'r')
text = fname.read()
words = text.split()
d = {}
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    try:
        first, second, third = words[i], words[i+1], words[i+2]
    except IndexError:
        break
    key = (first, second)

    if key not in d:
         d[key] = []
        #
d[key].append(third)
pprint(d)
#-------------------------generate text---------------------------
li = []
first, second = key
li.append(first)
li.append(second)
while True:
    try:
        third = choice(d[key]) 
    except KeyError:
        break
    li.append (second)
    li.append(third)
    if third[-1] in EOS: 
        break
    # else
    key = (second, third)
    first, second = key

gtext= ' '.join(li)
print gtext
```

my problem is when I run the code it always generates the last three words from the input file. I want it to generate new text randomly.

Comment: Should `d[key].append(third)` be after the `for`-loop or should it be a part of it?

Comment: yes it should be inside for loop, thanks